# List<List> confusion

Tags: c#, list

snippets of my code

```
List<List<optionsSort>> stocks = new List<List<optionsSort>>();
optionsSort tempStock1 = new optionsSort();
List<optionsSort> stock = new List<optionsSort>();
```

then some code,

```
for (int j = 1; j < optionsSt.Count; j++)
{

            if (optionsSt[j].isin == optionsSt[j - 1].isin)
            {

                tempStock1.name = optionsSt[j].name;
                tempStock1.date = optionsSt[j].date;
                tempStock1.strike = optionsSt[j].strike;
                tempStock1.size = optionsSt[j].size;
                tempStock1.isin = optionsSt[j].isin;
                tempStock1.callPut = optionsSt[j].callPut;

                stock.Add(tempStock1);

            }
            else
            {

                stocks.Add(stock);

                k = k + 1;
                stock.Clear();

                tempStock1.name = optionsSt[j].name;
                tempStock1.date = optionsSt[j].date;
                tempStock1.strike = optionsSt[j].strike;
                tempStock1.size = optionsSt[j].size;
                tempStock1.isin = optionsSt[j].isin;
                tempStock1.callPut = optionsSt[j].callPut;

                stock.Add(tempStock1);



            }




        }//endfor
```

Basicly, im going through a large list to sort elements into groups, a new List name stocks.

now the problem is, when I add to **stocks** all elements contained in the list stock and then clear stock on the next line to start again, I delete all the elements I have stored in **stocks**.

Any Ideas. Do I have to index stocks like stocks[i].Add(stock) so each block of similar stocks is an element in stocks.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `List<T>` objects, like all classes in .NET, are **reference** types. That means that every time you add `stock` to `stocks` you aren't adding a *new* list, you are only adding a reference to the *same* list in memory. So when you later call `Clear`, that is reflected both in your variable `stock` and in all other references in `stocks`.

You can resolve this by making a shallow copy of `stock` every time you add it to `stocks`:

```
stocks.Add(stock.ToList());
```

Comment: I dont know how you would even know that, but I salute you... it fixed the problem.... ive been going mental over it!!! books dont teach you the tricks...

Comment: @Timujin The difference between value and reference types is pretty fundamental to .NET programming. See [Value Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) / [Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx)

Comment: @Timujin I see that you're relatively new to Stack Overflow. If this or any other answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it for the benefit of the future visitors who may have the same issue as you. Also, if any answer has helped you, please upvote it even if it wasn't the solution you ended up going with. This helps to encourage well researched, quality answers.

Comment: I am. I did vote up and it did Answer my question. already continued with my program :-) Many thanks for this, it has really helped. Im trying to get to grips with c#, requires time and practise I guess

Comment: This answer helps with what the OP intended to **happen**, but not what he intended to **do**. `ToList()` is merely a hack in this case, at least IMHO.

Comment: @KendallFrey My interpretation of OP's code was that he intended to add a *copy* of `stock` to `stocks` on every iteration rather than adding a reference, and was reusing `stock` simply as a temporary variable--which is precisely how my answer works. In that case `Add(stock.ToList())` is just a shortened form of `Add(new List<optionsSort>(stock))`. But +1 since your solution works just as well (and actually saves an array copy on each iteration).

Comment: Question. now that I have this list<list> how would I iterate...

    for(i = 0; i<stocks.count; i++)
    {
      //say there are 30 elements, each element contains 60 elemenst
      //how would I access that, using a foreach??
    
     }

Comment: @Timujin Either `foreach(x in stocks) foreach(y in x) ...` *or* `foreach(x in stocks.SelectMany(y => y)) ...`.

Comment: Thanks, I pressed return to quick and not "shift return". What im trying to do is this. some elements say in the 5 "row" of the list may contain the same date but because the size is different I want to add the 2 sizes together and get rid of one of the entries.

so, for simplicity. if in stocks[0] there are 10 elements and of these 2 have the same date but are 2 different size, ill add those together and delete the one that is not the addition, so now in stocks[0] there will exist 9 elements

Comment: @Timujin You can also do `for(var i = 0; i < stocks.Count; i++) for(var j = 0; j < stocks[i].Count; j++) ...` if you'd like to iterate the lists by index. Hopefully this answers your second question.

Comment: @p.s.w.g, i have this question here, if you have any insight?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764498/changing-the-value-of-certain-elements-of-a-list

Answer (score 3):

You're not creating a **new list**, you're using **one list**, and filling it and clearing it repeatedly. Since your outer list contains only one list, repeated multiple times, that list will have the **same contents** in every instance. That is, when you clear your list, you can no longer access the old contents, even if you try to access them from inside the outer list.

What you need to do is to change this line:

```
stock.Clear();
```

To this:

```
stock = new List<optionsSort>();
```

That is what you *really* meant. :)

Comment: Thanks. The method provided by P.S.W.G also works and works well. I get the desired results. Ill try yours aswell, maybe more ways to skin the cat :-)